# Semantic-UI: Cheatsheet with all theme variables

Tags: variables, themes, semantic-ui, theming

As you can see at http://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html, there are predefined variables for each element, collection, module etc (for example button.variables: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/src/themes/amazon/elements/button.variables).

Unfortunally, I cannot find all the possible variables for each element, module, collection etc. Is there something like a cheatsheet with all possible theme variables for Semantic-UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are actually looking for is Labeled as Definitions under the folder src.

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor-Data/tree/master/lib/semantic-ui/src/definitions

Here is an example: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor-Data/blob/master/lib/semantic-ui/src/definitions/globals/site.import.less

You can only change a few variable for each tag, for example for body:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: @pageOverflowX;
  min-width: @pageMinWidth;
  background: @pageBackground;
  font-family: @pageFont;
  font-size: @fontSize;
  line-height: @lineHeight;
  color: @textColor;
  font-smoothing: @fontSmoothing;
}
```

Hope this helps you out!

Bests!

Jules